# How to set and print the value of json object in postgresql?

Tags: python, sql, django, postgresql, postgresql-9.1

What I have done till now is :

```
DO
$do$
DECLARE
    namz Text;
    jsonObject json = 
            '{
                "Name": "Kshitiz Kala",     
                "Education": "B.Tech", 
                "Skills": ["J2EE", "JDBC", "Html"]
            }';
BEGIN 
    SELECT jsonObject->'Name' into namz;
    select namz;
END
$do$
```

I am not finding any success here.

actual problem is I am passing a json Object to a stored procedure which will store the data in three different table 1) user table contains user_id, user_name, user_edu. 2) skill table contain skill_id, skill_name. 3) user_skill table contain id, user_id, usr_skill_id.

This is the json object I am passing from Django application

```
{"Name": "Kshitiz Kala", "Education": "B.Tech", "Skills": ["J2EE", "JDBC", "Html"]}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your json code is fine, just check:

```
SELECT '{"Name": "Kshitiz Kala",     
                "Education": "B.Tech", 
                "Skills": ["J2EE", "JDBC", "Html"]
            }'::json->'Name'
```

or in pgplsql:

```
DO
$do$
DECLARE
    namz Text;
    jsonObject json = 
            '{
                "Name": "Kshitiz Kala",     
                "Education": "B.Tech", 
                "Skills": ["J2EE", "JDBC", "Html"]
            }';
BEGIN 
    SELECT jsonObject->'Name' into namz;
    raise 'JSON value Name is %', namz;
END
$do$
```

Problem is somewhere else. Eg. last line in this block won't do anything (SELECT namz in plpgpsql)

Comment: How to store the skills in array In "skill_s TEXT[];" and is it the correct way to declare the empty array in postgresql?

Comment: Use json_array_elements_text just like `select array_agg(json_array_elements_text('{"Name": "Kshitiz Kala",     
                "Education": "B.Tech", 
                "Skills": ["J2EE", "JDBC", "Html"]
            }'::json->'Skills'))`